# Need jar for Base64 class in which it should have encodeBytes(String) method

Tags: java, jar, base64

I am unable to locate the jar file over internet where Base64 class has the method `encodeBytes(String)`. Please help me find the location of the downloadable jar file.

Comment: [This question and subsequent answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744715/howto-base64-encode-an-java-object-using-org-apache-commons-codec-binary-base64) details the use of Apache Commons to accomplish your goal.

Comment: It doesn't have encodeBytes method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) which you can download from [maven central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec)

### Update

Is this the library you are looking for. It has the `encodeBytes` method:
[click me](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/api/index.html)

Comment: Please clarify your question - are you looking for library that gets the job done, or a specific library?

Comment: Yes I'm looking for a specific library that gets my job done.  I have a java application which is using this this class Base64 with method encodeBytes(String). I need to make UP my application with this missing library.

Comment: If you know the name of the class can't you just look at the imports and just google the `fully qualified name` of the class ?

Comment: Good Question. :) If I do see the import statement in the java code then I could have find it in the google with full path. My bad luck and strange thing is, it doesn't have the import statement and I have to find jar and include import statement in it.

Answer (score 0):

As you are looking for a specific version of Apache Commons Codec that has `Base64.encodeBytes(String)`, you can search the source code archive [here](http://archive.apache.org/dist/commons/codec/source/).

Once you've identified the version you require you can get the jar file [here](http://archive.apache.org/dist/commons/codec/binaries/).

Comment: hmmm promising...May be older version does have this method. How can I find this info, Please suggest?

Comment: Along the lines of @SvetlinZarev's comment make sure to look at the fully qualified name of your `Base64` class to make sure it is indeed an Apache class.